# How to wire Mean Well RT-65D power supply?

Tags: power-supply, connector, wiring

I'm not very familiar with electronics. Especially I have never wired a 230 V power supply manually.
There is a [Mean Well RT-65D](https://www.schukat.com/schukat/pdf.nsf/index/A607D30CCD9F3AA4C1257A9A004094B8/$file/rt-65-spec.pdf) power supply.

I have a rubber connector with open wires blue, brown and yellow-green.
And I have a consumer which needs 24 V.

My suggestion is (*edited*):

```
brown => Pin 1 (AC/L)
blue => Pin 2 (AC/N)
yellow-green => Pin 3 (FG)
consumer +24V => Pin 6 (DC OUTPUT +V2)
consumer GND => Pin 7 (DC OUTPUT COM)
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Your output "ground" is "COM" - i.e., *common*.

Comment: FG is frame ground, and NC  is no connection.

Comment: Honestly, you are fiddling with different wirings some of which bearing dangerous voltages. There are lots of caveats regarding the use of modular PSUs like that one. e.g. creeping distances, EMC, proper grounding, strain relief, proper housing... I assume you to lack knowledge about those problems, too. I strongly discourage you from using this PSU because misuse can result in serious health hazards. You should switch to a class II brick PSU or wall wart, depending on the power needed. And "NC" means "not connected"

Comment: @PeterBennett In this case FG means functional ground. If it is also connected to the frame I can't tell. But the block diagram exhibits a ground symbol in a circle, which definitely means functional ground.

Comment: Thanks for your kind replies. I have edited my post so it should be correct now? So I don't use NC. @Ariser It's inside an existing housing. I would never power-on this by myself. I will only make a suggestion and then ask my master thesis supervisor. Thanks for the well-meant critical advice.

Comment: Sorry for my harsh critizism. If you aren't doing this on your own, there is little to fear. I've seen many dangerous devices and developed an attitude like: better a verbal strike than an electric strike :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connection looksvcorrect though you should mention which country you are working in as different countries have different AC wires color codes

Comment: Yes I know, thats a good point. [Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power#Color_codes), so L1 brown and Neutral green.

Comment: @wenzul Ah, no. Please read carefully! Neutral is blue, whereever it can be determined exactly. Green/Yellow-striped is protective earth. If your cable is connected via an CE-Plug (CEE 7/4), you cannot be sure, that blue is neutral and brown is live, as it depends from the orientation of your plug relatively to the wall outlet.

Comment: Sorry I mixed the colors. I meant L1 brown, Neutral blue of course. Yes it's connected via CEE 7/4. So I just wire the right colors but there is no preference? Sounds logical, since the german ones are not protected against reverse polarity. Regarding the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power#Color_codes) I can be sure that this color combination is unique for Europe? So I don't have to care if the plug is shipped from another continent, right?